# How to calculate the number of non-zero fields in a row and using that make a query in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

My model

```
from django.db import models

class Books(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    field_2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ..........................
    field_6 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now I want to make a query to count the number of ***Books*** where exactly 3 fields are non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
Books.objects.annotate(
    v1 = Case(
        When(field_1=0,then=1),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ),
    v2 = Case(
        When(field_2=0,then=1),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ),
    v3 = Case(
        When(field_3=0,then=1),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
    # ....
).annotate(
      non_zero_sum=F('v1')+F('v2')+F('v3')+F('v4')+F('v5')+F('v6')
).filter(non_zero_sum=3)
```

But IMHO, the model design is not correct. If you have same type of fields multiple times, and can be non zero, it is better to create ForeignKey Relation for this:

```
class SomeField(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='fields')
```

Then you could have tried like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Book.objects.annotate(c = Count('fields')).filter(c__gte=3)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Your solution will work for sum of zero valued field actually but i modified it anyway.